# How to make waveform chart in LabVIEW?

Tags: graph, labview

I am working on a project using LabVIEW. And I have data from Thingspeak, which is data `created at` and `field 1` values. I want to display these data in my application.

How do I combine that data into one graph, so the `create at` will be X axis, and `field 1` will be Y axis?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include both arrays in a cluster and use an XY Graph. 
Take a look at NI documentation about XY Graphs, they are easy to use and I think that can answer your questions.

https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019NAfSAM

If one of the axis are timestamps, check if you are able to take a t0 (initial value of time) and dt (interval between samples) you can build a waveform, that will allow you to save memory in case your using big amounts of data. 
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvwave/build_waveform/